# Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to exception_handler()

Tags: php, csv

I want to import a csv file and so I write my PHP code, it functions good, but since I add something I get this error:

> ''Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   exception_handler() ...''

```html
$parts = explode(',', $tmp[6]);

 $fachrichtung = sistr($parts[1],'LA', true);

 if ($fachrichtung == 'LA'){
     $fachrichtung = 'Lehramt' ;
 } else {
     $fachrichtung = substr($parts[0],strrpos($parts[0], " ") );
 }
```

And my query function works well without the code above, but I need it.

query: ..... `'".utf8_encode (trim($fachrichtung,"""))."'`,.......

Why I get the error?

Comment: 1. Please post a var_dump() of $parts. 
2. *sistr* does not appear to ba PHP function. Did you mean *substr*?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to reinvent the wheel here. Try using [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) function instead. It should give you more predictable results, and hopefully preclude the error from happening in the first place.

Additionally it appears that it's complaining you're passing something other than an exception to the exception Handler.

You should be able to remedy this with the try-catch statement.

See also: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php